# VHDL enumerator relational operators

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm currently programming a system in VHDL, and I'm using an enumerator from another package called vnir, which is defined as such:

```
package vnir is
    type row_type_t is (ROW_NONE, ROW_NIR, ROW_BLUE, ROW_RED);
end package vnir;
```

I've defined my architecture as such

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.vnir;

entity imaging_buffer is
    port(
        clock           : in std_logic;
        reset_n         : in std_logic;
        vnir_row_ready  : in vnir.row_type_t
    );
end entity imaging_buffer;

architecture rtl of imaging_buffer is
    signal vnir_row_ready_i : vnir.row_type_t;
begin
    vnir_pipeline : process (reset_n, clock) is
    begin
        if (reset_n = '0') then
            vnir_row_ready_i <= vnir.ROW_NONE;
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if (vnir_row_ready /= vnir.ROW_NONE) then
                --do stuff
            end if;
       end if;
    end process vnir_pipeline;
end architecture;
```

The internal signal vnir_row_ready_i can be assigned to no problem, however the relational operator doesn't seem to work as ModelSim throws this error when I try to compile:

```
# ** Error: C:/Users/nashg/Documents/iris_project/ex2_iris/vhdl/subsystems/sdram/Imaging Buffer/test.vhd(23): (vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator '/='.
# ** Error: C:/Users/nashg/Documents/iris_project/ex2_iris/vhdl/subsystems/sdram/Imaging Buffer/test.vhd(23): Type error resolving infix expression "/=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
# ** Error: C:/Users/nashg/Documents/iris_project/ex2_iris/vhdl/subsystems/sdram/Imaging Buffer/test.vhd(28): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. What is the type of `vnir_row_ready`? It doesn't appear to be of type `row_type_t`. The inequality operator is defined for any type other than a protected type. It's required the operands g3 of the same type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've updated my question to reflect it! I thought that I had created the same type of signal, but perhaps I've made a mistake when I declared it or I'm not using it properly?

Comment: Still not a [mcve] without the design unit vnir (which appears to be a package) and something than can be analyzed (compiled, analysis is a VHDL term of art).

Comment: Sorry, thanks for helping me get familiar. Hopefully my latest edit addresses this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker helped me figure out how to make it work! I think that the /= operator is created in the vnir scope, but not ported over to the entity I'm working on. By writing :`use work.vnir."/=";` at the beginning of the file it compiles, so the full entity looks like so:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.vnir;
use work.vnir."/=";

entity imaging_buffer is
    port(
        clock           : in std_logic;
        reset_n         : in std_logic;
        vnir_row_ready  : in vnir.row_type_t
    );
end entity imaging_buffer;

architecture rtl of imaging_buffer is
    signal vnir_row_ready_i : vnir.row_type_t;
begin
    vnir_pipeline : process (reset_n, clock) is
    begin
        if (reset_n = '0') then
            vnir_row_ready_i <= vnir.ROW_NONE;
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if (vnir_row_ready /= vnir.ROW_NONE) then
                --do stuff
            end if;
       end if;
    end process vnir_pipeline;
end architecture;
```

Alternatively it did work by including `use work.vnir.all;` and taking out the vnir. before the types, but that wasn't possible with the project I'm working one

Comment: You could also `use work.vnir.all;` and drop all the selected name prefixes (vnir.). The relational operators are all implicitly declared immediately following a type declaration (other than a protected type). Your method didn't originally make the declaration visible. The `all` suffix for a use clause makes every declaration in the declarative region of the prefix directly visible. Likewise `if  vnir."/="(vnir_row_ready, vnir.ROW_NONE) then` would work where the function implementing the relational operator is called by selected name (which can't be done for operators).

Comment: You could also make the relational operator visible with an alias declaration either as an entity, architecture or process declarative item.